# get_the_author_meta() not working on wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some problems with the standard wp function [get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/). I use it in my project to display the social link of an author but I always get an empty variable.

Here is my code in article page:

```
    $author_name = get_the_author();//not empty
    $author_info = get_the_author_meta('description');//not empty
    $author_website = get_the_author_meta('url');//empty
    
    $author_facebook = get_the_author_meta('facebook');//empty
    $author_twitter = get_the_author_meta('twitter');//empty
    $author_google = get_the_author_meta('google');//empty
    $author_linkedin = get_the_author_meta('linkedin','7');//also empty whit this desperate attempt
    $author_instagram = get_the_author_meta('instagram',7);//also empty whit this desperate attempt
```

I tested on an article of an author with all social link.
I have no php an no js error.
I installed cimy user extra fields.

Comment: Why don't you dump the author data first to see if those fields are there in the first place.

Comment: var_dump(get_the_author_meta());//string(0) ""
     var_dump(get_the_author_meta(7));//string(0) ""
     var_dump(get_the_author_meta('7'));//string(0) ""

The very strage thing is that all those fields exist and are not empty in the DB.

Comment: Something tells me you are using a plugin to add those social links to the author. The fields that are returning empty strings are not valid ones according to the Codex. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta

Comment: Yes, I add it. You can find the exact metas (facebook, Twitter excetera) on DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have an extra comma here $author_facebook = get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', ); //empty

I'm guessing this was an error in the copy paste, otherwise you get a very specific 'unexpected token' error. With that exception your code should work. You might be getting this error for two reasons:

1. The plugin you are using to add the user meta is not working correctly.
2. The actual author of the page / post does not have the meta data set correctly.

This code worked for me, try this just to test:

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook', 'https://facebook.com' );

var_dump( $user_id );
var_dump( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ) );

// Output: string(20) "https://facebook.com"
```

You mentioned before that you can see the social media links on the DB under usermeta, so my guess is that the current author of the post / page does not have the social media links set. On the var_dumps of the code you will see the user ID. Find on the DB all the entries of the table usermeta with that user ID and you will notice there is no custom meta for that specific user.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the explanation. Now I finally get the complete process. I also have an extra error:
- I replace "**google**" with "**googleplus**"